# Android app splash screen from file on device

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-theme

I want to display a splash screen for x seconds at the app launch from a PNG file on the device.

I have tried android:windowBackground in the theme however that cannot be taken from a file and only predefined Drawable

The file may change at anytime so at next app launch it will be different.

Comment: Set ImageView or just a View equal to the screen size in your Activity layout and set it's background with any image in your Activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the code to set timer for Splash Screen activity. Also, do not forget to include the activity in manifest.

**splash_screen.java**

```
public class Splash extends Activity {         
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);

            Thread timerThread = new Thread(){
                public void run(){
                    try{
                        sleep(5000);  //Change the timing of the Screen
                    }catch(InterruptedException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }finally{
                        Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this,MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
            };
            timerThread.start();
        }  
     }
```

Make your layout, full screen, remove action bar. Here's the code for **splash_screen.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:background="@drawable/splashscreen"
 android:orientation="vertical">

</LinearLayout>
```

Change the image of splashscreen, when you need, in your case, each time app is launched. HTH.

Comment: Although doesn't explicitly explain how to read a new file into a Drawable object this is good code for a splash screen.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Change the source of `android:background="@drawable/splashscreen"` to your drawable resource, and it changes in splashscreen too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ImageView.
Set scale image to fit the screen.
Make window fullscreen with no titlebar. By this you can set drawable different every time.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:background="@drawable/splashscreen"
 android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/image2"
             />
</LinearLayout>
```

Access this ImageView in splash screen activity by..

```
ImageView img = (ImageView) findviewbyId(R.id.imageView);
Bitmap bitmapImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePathFromSDCard);
    Drawable drawableImage = new BitmapDrawable(bitmapImage);

    img.setBackgroundDrawable(drawableImage);
```

Comment: An answer on Stackoverflow typically contains a few more details like a code example, ... maybe you could provide it. It would make this answer definitely more useful.